# How can I add collision hitboxes to a rectangle(and my player) in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, 2d, p5.js

I'm trying to make an among us replica, and I want my player, (Mover) to not be able to go through my rectangles. I am fairly new to coding(JavaScript in general) and I would like some help creating hitboxes for my game. https://editor.p5js.org/LttntLark/sketches/JBSg2zIfEf                  all of the code is right there, and as always, all help is appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify, none of the map has been made yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement the collision detection by yourself you'll probably want to read specific resources and be ready to do some math.

But you could also use a p5 library like [p5.collide2d](https://github.com/bmoren/p5.collide2D). Once it is added to your project, the library provides some functions like [collideRectRect()](https://github.com/bmoren/p5.collide2D#colliderectrect) which takes the position and size of two rectangles and returns `true` if they are colliding.

Another useful library is [p5.play](https://molleindustria.github.io/p5.play/) which handles your sprites and the whole physic system of your game. It's a very basic library so it's not great for big complex projects, but to get started with programming and playing with physics it's a good starting point.

The p5.js website has [a page](https://p5js.org/libraries/) listing the community libraries which might be useful too.